# How to convert raw javascript object to a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping

When screen-scraping some website, I extract data from `<script>` tags.
The data I get is not in standard `JSON` format. I cannot use `json.loads()`.

```py
# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
```

Currently, I use `regex` to transform the raw data to `JSON` format.
But I feel pretty bad when I encounter complicated data structure.

Do you have some better solutions?

Comment: What is non-standard about the data you want to parse?

Comment: @HuuNguyen I want to parse `Plain old javascript data structure` to python object.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that `js_obj` didn't have quotes around the keys. How complicated would your data structures get? It's hard to suggest anything without knowing the cases you're trying to solve for.

Comment: @HuuNguyen `js_obj` maybe nested

Comment: there are similar questions on SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10057449/384442 none of them is offering any ready to use solution

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### [`demjson.decode()`](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson)

```py
import demjson

# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = demjson.decode(js_obj)
```

### [`chompjs.parse_js_object()`](https://github.com/Nykakin/chompjs)

```py
import chompjs

# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = chompjs.parse_js_object(js_obj)
```

### [`jsonnet.evaluate_snippet()`](https://github.com/google/jsonnet)

```py
import json, _jsonnet

# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet('snippet', js_obj))
```

### [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import ast

# from
js_obj = "{'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}"

# to
py_obj = ast.literal_eval(js_obj)
```

Comment: JSON does not support circular object

Comment: Links to demjson and jsonnet are dead

Comment: demjson is giving problems with Python 3 because Setuptools has removed support for 2to3. So it may not be a valid alternative for those using python 3.X right now.

Comment: For `jsonnet` I am getting: `/home/hafiz031/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_jsonnet.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv
`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_jsonnet'

Comment: note that `chompjs` is much faster than `json5` (about 50% less time, matters especially with large complex objects).

Answer (score 16):

### Use [json5](https://pypi.org/project/json5/)

```
import json5

js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

py_obj = json5.loads(js_obj)

print(py_obj)

# output
# {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Comment: This is the best one :)

Comment: **Caution**: unless you have very small object, don't use JSON5, it's explicitely stated in their documentation that it is slow. And they are not lying, it is very very slow even on average size JSON. Test it on a real usecase befeore adopting this. (I tested version 0.9.8)

Answer (score 8):

I'm facing the same problem this afternoon, and I finally found a quite good solution. That is [JSON5](https://json5.org/).

The syntax of JSON5 is more similar to native JavaScript, so it can help you parse non-standard JSON objects.

You might want to check [pyjson5](https://github.com/dpranke/pyjson5) out.

Comment: This is the fastest library. I tried using demjson, my script ran 10.5s. Pyjson5 completes this task in 0.004s.

Comment: @Inventor can you post an example of how this works?

Answer (score 4):

If you have `node` available on the system, you can ask it to evaluate the javascript expression for you, and print the stringified result. The resulting JSON can then be fed to `json.loads`:

```py
def evaluate_javascript(s):
    """Evaluate and stringify a javascript expression in node.js, and convert the
    resulting JSON to a Python object"""
    node = Popen(['node', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    stdout, _ = node.communicate(f'console.log(JSON.stringify({s}))'.encode('utf8'))
    return json.loads(stdout.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: After trying other suggestions, I finally finish my problem with this solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This will likely not work everywhere, but as a start, here's a simple regex that should convert the keys into quoted strings so you can pass into json.loads.  Or is this what you're already doing?

```
In[70] : quote_keys_regex = r'([\{\s,])(\w+)(:)'

In[71] : re.sub(quote_keys_regex, r'\1"\2"\3', js_obj)
Out[71]: '{"x":1, "y":2, "z":3}'

In[72] : js_obj_2 = '{x:1, y:2, z:{k:3,j:2}}'

Int[73]: re.sub(quote_keys_regex, r'\1"\2"\3', js_obj_2)
Out[73]: '{"x":1, "y":2, "z":{"k":3,"j":2}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Not including objects**

## [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.loads)

- `json.loads()` doesn't accept **undefined**, you have to change to **null**
- `json.loads()` **only** accept double quotes

  - `{"foo": 1, "bar": null}`

Use this if you are sure that your javascript code only have double quotes on key names.

```py
import json

json_text = """{"foo": 1, "bar": undefined}"""
json_text = re.sub(r'("\s*:\s*)undefined(\s*[,}])', '\\1null\\2', json_text)

py_obj = json.loads(json_text)
```

## [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

- `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't accept **undefined**, you have to change to **None**
- `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't accept **null**, you have to change to **None**
- `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't accept **true**, you have to change to **True**
- `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't accept **false**, you have to change to **False**
- `ast.literal_eval()` accept single and double quotes

  - `{"foo": 1, "bar": None}` or `{'foo': 1, 'bar': None}`

```py
import ast

js_obj = """{'foo': 1, 'bar': undefined}"""
js_obj = re.sub(r'([\'\"]\s*:\s*)undefined(\s*[,}])', '\\1None\\2', js_obj)
js_obj = re.sub(r'([\'\"]\s*:\s*)null(\s*[,}])', '\\1None\\2', js_obj)
js_obj = re.sub(r'([\'\"]\s*:\s*)NaN(\s*[,}])', '\\1None\\2', js_obj)
js_obj = re.sub(r'([\'\"]\s*:\s*)true(\s*[,}])', '\\1True\\2', js_obj)
js_obj = re.sub(r'([\'\"]\s*:\s*)false(\s*[,}])', '\\1False\\2', js_obj)

py_obj = ast.literal_eval(js_obj)
```