# How to decode JavaScript response in python 3.4+?

Tags: javascript, python

I got this response from a website. I really don't know how to decode it and get the information that I want.

Here is the JavaScript response:

```
{header:{code:0,message:{title:"",detail:""}},body:{parameters:{},dataStores:{"kccjStore":{pageSize:100,pageNumber:1,recordCount:3,name:"kccjStore",rowSetName:"pojo_com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel",order:"kclb asc",metaData:{"jxbmc":{dataType:12},"njzypm":{dataType:12},"xh":{dataType:12},"jxbh":{dataType:12},"sftg":{dataType:12},"zzcj":{dataType:12},"cjzt":{dataType:12},"bzw":{dataType:12},"class":{dataType:12},"xs":{dataType:12},"xq":{dataType:12},"jsxm":{dataType:12},"xnd":{dataType:12},"resource_id":{dataType:12},"jxbpm":{dataType:12},"jd":{dataType:12},"kch":{dataType:12},"kcywmc":{dataType:12},"kcmc":{dataType:12},"khfs":{dataType:12},"cjlcId":{dataType:12},"xf":{dataType:12},"kclb":{dataType:12},"zpcj":{dataType:12}},rowSet:{primary:[{"jxbpm":"79\/93","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"11895237815","kcywmc":"Mobile Information Engineering Training:Intermediate ","jxbh":"46000092161002","zpcj":"90","resource_id":"11895237815","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000092","kcmc":"移动信息工程实训（中级）","kclb":"11","xf":"3.0","xs":"72.0","zzcj":"90","jd":"4.0","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"304\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"},{"jxbpm":"74\/128","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"12825792491","kcywmc":"Database Systems Lab","jxbh":"46000085161003","jsxm":"桑应朋","khfs":"03","zpcj":"94","resource_id":"12825792491","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000085","kcmc":"数据库系统实验","kclb":"21","xf":"1.0","xs":"36.0","zzcj":"94","jd":"4.4","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"157\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"},{"jxbpm":"20\/167","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"12825622928","kcywmc":"Database Systems","jxbh":"46000084161001","jsxm":"桑应朋","khfs":"01","zpcj":"87","resource_id":"12825622928","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000084","kcmc":"数据库系统","kclb":"21","xf":"2.0","xs":"36.0","zzcj":"87","jd":"3.7","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"34\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"}]}}}}}
```

I am working with Python 3.4. Below is my code

```
html_doc = opener.open('http://wjw.sysu.edu.cn/api/score?year=2016-2017&term=1&pylb=01').read().decode('utf-8')
```

Thanks in advance!

——————————————————

I mistakenly thought it was a JSON file before and asked a bad question. I'm sorry for that. But thank you for helping me! Hope some of you can help me with my new question!

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'json' like file. It either is or it isn't. You'll need to put each property within double quotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In particular you did not show us exactly what you tried and what was not working.  This makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: Looks like some raw javascript, not json

Comment: I am actually new to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your guide. I will read it later. Fortunately, my question seems to solved.@Stephen Rauch

Comment: I actually don't know what kind of file it is. Some of my friends mentioned that it may be a JSON file. But someone mentioned that it is a JS file. Thanks for your help.@KeithJohnHutchison

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your input:

1. The braces on your input are unbalanced. You're missing the opening brace, `{`.
2. JSON requires that all keys be quoted using double quotes. Your input uses a different syntax, which is valid Javascript but not valid JSON. You *can* parse such objects into python dictionaries, if you really have to, using a third party package such as [`demjson`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900181/419876).

```python
>>> import demjson
>>> parsed = demjson.decode('{header:{code:0,message:{title:"",detail:""}}}')
>>> parsed
{u'header': {u'message': {u'detail': '', u'title': ''}, u'code': 0}}
```

That being said, your original instinct to use `json.loads` was generally correct. If you have any control over your input whatsoever (e.g. if it's the output of an API or script that you can re-write,) you *should re-write it to output strict JSON*, making it parsable by `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're data is not strictly JSON because some of the keys are not strings.

Also, there seems to be a missing matching curly brace -- should add as the first character,

```
{header:{code:0,message:{title:"",detail:""}},body:{parameters:{},dataStores:{"kccjStore":{pageSize:100,pageNumber:1,recordCount:3,name:"kccjStore",rowSetName:"pojo_com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel",order:"kclb asc",metaData:{"jxbmc":{dataType:12},"njzypm":{dataType:12},"xh":{dataType:12},"jxbh":{dataType:12},"sftg":{dataType:12},"zzcj":{dataType:12},"cjzt":{dataType:12},"bzw":{dataType:12},"class":{dataType:12},"xs":{dataType:12},"xq":{dataType:12},"jsxm":{dataType:12},"xnd":{dataType:12},"resource_id":{dataType:12},"jxbpm":{dataType:12},"jd":{dataType:12},"kch":{dataType:12},"kcywmc":{dataType:12},"kcmc":{dataType:12},"khfs":{dataType:12},"cjlcId":{dataType:12},"xf":{dataType:12},"kclb":{dataType:12},"zpcj":{dataType:12}},rowSet:{primary:[{"jxbpm":"79\/93","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"11895237815","kcywmc":"Mobile Information Engineering Training:Intermediate ","jxbh":"46000092161002","zpcj":"90","resource_id":"11895237815","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000092","kcmc":"移动信息工程实训（中级）","kclb":"11","xf":"3.0","xs":"72.0","zzcj":"90","jd":"4.0","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"304\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"},{"jxbpm":"74\/128","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"12825792491","kcywmc":"Database Systems Lab","jxbh":"46000085161003","jsxm":"桑应朋","khfs":"03","zpcj":"94","resource_id":"12825792491","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000085","kcmc":"数据库系统实验","kclb":"21","xf":"1.0","xs":"36.0","zzcj":"94","jd":"4.4","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"157\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"},{"jxbpm":"20\/167","bzw":"00","cjzt":"2","cjlcId":"12825622928","kcywmc":"Database Systems","jxbh":"46000084161001","jsxm":"桑应朋","khfs":"01","zpcj":"87","resource_id":"12825622928","xnd":"2016-2017","xq":"1","kch":"46000084","kcmc":"数据库系统","kclb":"21","xf":"2.0","xs":"36.0","zzcj":"87","jd":"3.7","sftg":"1","xh":"14353379","njzypm":"34\/403","class":"class com.neusoft.education.sysu.xscj.xscjcx.model.KccjModel"}]}}}}}
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) is a link to w3schools` JSON reference.

[Here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) is a JSON formatter/validator.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use third party library, you can just clean up the data by yourself using regex (eg. adding double quote to remaining properties):

```
import re
import json

text = # the input string

p = re.compile(r'({|,)([^{}:"]+):')
text = p.sub(r'\1"\2":', '{' + text)
obj = json.loads(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the first curl brace. The code below can help you parse the data to json:

```
s = <YOUR DATA>
import json
import re

def repl(m):
    return '"%s":'%m.group(1)

s = re.sub(r'(\w+):', repl, s)
o = json.loads(s)
print o
```