# how to get matched substring list in a json-type string with python?

Tags: python, json, match

I am trying to find all matched substrings from a input string below:

```
{
  covAnalyzeArgs : [
    "--disable-default",        
    "-co",
    "UNINIT_FOR_MISRA:enable_write_context:yes"
  ],
  fileOptions : [
    {
      optionName : "misra-config",
      fileContents : "{\n    version : \"2.0\",\n    standard : \"c2012\",\n    title: \"Covererd\",\n    deviations : [\n\n{ deviation: \"Directive 4.3\", reason: \"This rule is currently disabled in the analysis configuration.\" },\n{ deviation: \"Directive 4.4\", reason: \"This rule is currently disabled in the analysis configuration.\" },\n{ deviation: \"Rule 21.12\", reason: \"This rule is currently disabled in the analysis configuration.\" },\n{ deviation: \"Rule 22.3\", reason: \"This rule is currently disabled in the analysis configuration.\" }\n\t\t\n    ]\n}\n"
    }
  ],
  fileCheckerOptions : [
    {
      checkerName : "PW.*_FOR_MISRA",
      optionName : "config_file",
      fileContents : "// Level 1\nchk \"PW.SET_BUT_NOT_USED\": on;\nchk \"PW.TRIGRAPH_IGNORED\": on;\nchk \"SW.SYM_NOT_A_TEMPLATE\": off;\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think that this string is very similar to 'json data' and what I want to find is directive and rule numbers list such as 'Directive 4.3' or 'Rule 22.3'.
But when I try to covert the to json object, it fails

```
decoded = json.loads(input_string)
```

Could you let me know how to covert it to json data?
And also do you have any idea to extract directive and rule numbers?

Comment: Your json is invalid.

Comment: That seems like a javascript object. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The json you're trying to load isn't valid json. The key name must be wrapped in double quotes.

`"version": "2.0"`

Not

`version: "2.0"`