# Extract Array elements from html

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm using urlopen and beautifulsoup4 to fetch the contents of a webpage.
The webpage I'm fetching generates some dynamic javascript blocks.
I would like to extract the contents of an entire array.

The array is in the following format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jobmap = {};
jobmap[0]= {jk:'929a2508c8bf2c9c',efccid: '28d4bd688c1e4e86',srcid:'4beb17a7fc4b64e2',cmpid:'be1c2a3db344744f',num:'0',srcname:'City of Oshawa',cmp:'City of Oshawa',cmpesc:'City of Oshawa',cmplnk:'/City-of-Oshawa-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Oshawa, ON',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'Oshawa',title:'Systems Analyst',locid:'da5ca33120fa5fe5',rd:'8i0xAbEkuWUhy6dasPEQkceDzWLtCZmZLj2Y-bGYlQI'};
jobmap[1]= {jk:'2d06bbaac441e7d2',efccid: 'beb412fe8b0feacc',srcid:'0a0f0bf6b7639c78',cmpid:'0c05d4e9f9f0206d',num:'1',srcname:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmp:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmpesc:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmplnk:'/FGL-Sports-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Ontario',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'',title:'Decision Support Analyst',locid:'8b17acc5f001bdbf',rd:'v7_ZQyGHijdq7ng-cswbFDpj7KoE_Ia4YknbAcijYgE'};
</script>
```

The array contains an unknown number of elements.
How can I extract the contents of the whole array and save it into an json object?

Comment: That's an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) not an Array.

Comment: If you have dynamic content, Beautilsoup and urlopen are the wrong way to approach the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it depends.., sometimes javascript content is present in the HTML (usually in script tags) and it makes sense to go the "easy" urlopen/requests approach to avoid the overhead and slowness of the browser-based or javascript-engine based way. Though, here things are generally more fragile. It's probably not strictly "wrong", but more like "use with caution and understanding" :)

Comment: @alecxe Fair points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` can help to solve only a part of the problem - locating the desired `script` element containing the desired object. Then, you would need to use either *javascript parser*, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit), or *regular expressions*, for example, something along these lines:

```
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<script type="text/javascript">
var jobmap = {};
jobmap[0]= {jk:'929a2508c8bf2c9c',efccid: '28d4bd688c1e4e86',srcid:'4beb17a7fc4b64e2',cmpid:'be1c2a3db344744f',num:'0',srcname:'City of Oshawa',cmp:'City of Oshawa',cmpesc:'City of Oshawa',cmplnk:'/City-of-Oshawa-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Oshawa, ON',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'Oshawa',title:'Systems Analyst',locid:'da5ca33120fa5fe5',rd:'8i0xAbEkuWUhy6dasPEQkceDzWLtCZmZLj2Y-bGYlQI'};
jobmap[1]= {jk:'2d06bbaac441e7d2',efccid: 'beb412fe8b0feacc',srcid:'0a0f0bf6b7639c78',cmpid:'0c05d4e9f9f0206d',num:'1',srcname:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmp:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmpesc:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmplnk:'/FGL-Sports-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Ontario',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'',title:'Decision Support Analyst',locid:'8b17acc5f001bdbf',rd:'v7_ZQyGHijdq7ng-cswbFDpj7KoE_Ia4YknbAcijYgE'};
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: "var jobmap" in text)

pattern = re.compile(r"jobmap\[\d+\]\s*=\s*({.*?})")
for item in pattern.findall(script.get_text(), re.MULTILINE):
    print(item)
```

Prints:

```
{jk:'929a2508c8bf2c9c',efccid: '28d4bd688c1e4e86',srcid:'4beb17a7fc4b64e2',cmpid:'be1c2a3db344744f',num:'0',srcname:'City of Oshawa',cmp:'City of Oshawa',cmpesc:'City of Oshawa',cmplnk:'/City-of-Oshawa-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Oshawa, ON',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'Oshawa',title:'Systems Analyst',locid:'da5ca33120fa5fe5',rd:'8i0xAbEkuWUhy6dasPEQkceDzWLtCZmZLj2Y-bGYlQI'}
{jk:'2d06bbaac441e7d2',efccid: 'beb412fe8b0feacc',srcid:'0a0f0bf6b7639c78',cmpid:'0c05d4e9f9f0206d',num:'1',srcname:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmp:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmpesc:'FGL Sports Ltd.',cmplnk:'/FGL-Sports-jobs-in-Ontario',loc:'Ontario',country:'CA',zip:'',city:'',title:'Decision Support Analyst',locid:'8b17acc5f001bdbf',rd:'v7_ZQyGHijdq7ng-cswbFDpj7KoE_Ia4YknbAcijYgE'}
```

Note that each `item` value is *not directly loadable* with `json.loads()`, look into using [`demjson.decode()`](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/demjson-2.2.3/docs/demjson.html#-decode) or some other way to load the javascript object strings into Python dictionaries:

- [How to convert raw javascript object to python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary)