# extracting javascript array variables using regex returns a list of tuples

Tags: javascript, python, regex, beautifulsoup

My python regex using `re` is returning a list of tuples where I only expect a simple list.

I am scraping over 100 webpages using beautiful soup to obtain software version information that is returned in a javascript array. The script loops over a list of IP addresses and version info is logged to file.

Example source:

```
<script language="Javascript">
var active='2';
Appname[0]='foobar';
Appversion[0]='6.02 TEST prod';
Appversion[0]='6.02 TEST ';
Appname[1]='barfoo';
Appversion[1]='06.0001.00';
Appversion[1]='06.0001.00';
Appname[1]='barfoo';
Appversion[1]='06.0001.00';
Appversion[1]='06.0001.00';
</script>
```

As you can see the second array element is usually declared twice, and sometimes four times (but not on all instances of the retrieved web page). I would like to simply take the last value assigned. The `active` variable is one more than the required array element. There are other arrays and variables omitted for clarity.

Desired output for the example:

```
<ip addr>  1  barfoo  06.0001.00
```

My code is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238211/extract-array-elements-from-html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926451/how-to-match-but-not-capture-part-of-a-regex):

```
jscript = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: "var Appversion" in text)
# following lookaround regex; match but discard active=' and '; to return only the assigned value
regex = r"(?<=active=')((.*)(?=';))"
pattern = re.compile(regex)
active = pattern.search(jscript.get_text(), re.MULTILINE)
index = int(active.group())-1
pstring = pstring + '\t' + str(index)
array_names = ["Appname", "Appversion"]
for name in array_names:
    regex=r"(?<=" + name + r"\[" + str(index) + r"\]=')((.*)(?=';))"
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    name_match = pattern.findall(jscript.get_text(), re.MULTILINE)
    last_index = len(name_match)-1
    # no idea why we have tuples, what do we have 
    print(name_match)
    #  crashes for Appversion in example
    pstring = pstring + '\t' + name_match[last_index][last_index]
```

The output from `print (name_match)` is:

```
[('barfoo', 'barfoo'), ('barfoo', 'barfoo')]
[('06.0001.00', '06.0001.00'), ('06.0001.00', '06.0001.00'), ('06.0001.00', '06.0001.00'), ('06.0001.00', '06.0001.00')]
```

I thought regex would do the job: do a findall and then take the last index `name_match[last_index]`. But each match is a tuple and I do not understand why this is the case.

`name_match[last_index][last_index]` works for the Appname (by luck, I think), but not for Appversion.
Why does the regex return a tuple? How do I ensure the regex returns a simple  list of matches or otherwise code correctly? I think my regex declaration using lookaround is OK (the same format works fine to extract the value of `active`). This is my first time using `re` and I think of it as `grep`.

Comment: Remove all unnecessary capturing group parentheses, or convert all capturing groups to non-capturing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't see that this is a duplicate; the accepted answer on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird) did not change the regex grouping, although your solution did. But your comment above is different and helpful. when I remove the "group of groups" from the regex it works: `regex=r"(?<=" + name + r"\[" + str(index) + r"\]=')(.*)(?=';)"`. Thanks for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as I understand it, the problem here is that the group of groups used by findall in my original code caused a second instance of the match which was output as a tuple of identical matches.

Comment: This is marked as a dupe because you asked why re.findall returns a tuple, and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970) explains that well enough. The solution is natural: get rid of the unnecessary capturing groups by either removing redundant ones or by converting those that group subpatterns into non-capturing ones. Do you think I need to add it to my answer there?

Comment: No one will read a post that says "my re.findall returns unexpected null results" and think it's the same as "my re.findall returns duplicates of the expected match in a tuple". Sure, it might be the same underlying cause but i wouldn't say that's sufficient. I did not find your answer useful except that it links to the re.findall doco. What I did find useful is your comment above to remove groups. As it stands I can't mark this as answered or give you any credit and  the accepted answer of the "dupe" is not a solution here. But thanks again for the clue I needed.

Comment: I [updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).