# convert a string into python or json dictionary whose keys are not quoted

Tags: javascript, json, python-2.7

Imagine the following in python (using 2.7):

**myString = '{ key: "value" }'**

"value" could be a simple string, a list, a boolean or another dictionary, each of which really is in double quotes

If I try to convert this into a python dictionary or json, I fail because the key, in the original string is not quoted.

For example:

- **ast.literal_eval(myString)** results in: IndentationError: unexpected indent or ValueError: malformed string (depending on the complexity of myString)
- **eval(myString)** results in: NameError: name 'AbsolutePath' is not defined
- **json.loads(myString)** results in: ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes ...

Effectively, I am getting this string from a var declaration in javascript that is being scraped from the page.  myString could be storing a dictionary with 50 to 100 entries.

I don't believe this is the same as asked elsewhere since the key is unquoted and the value is.

Comment: import ast
import json

myString = '{ key: "value" }'

print (ast.literal_eval(myString))
print (eval(myString))
print (json.loads(myString))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert raw javascript object to python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary)

Comment: By scraping do you mean you are just pulling literal Javascript code into the string? I'm not sure how well that will work, if you can modify the javascript, use `JSON.stringify` and something like [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/docs) to decode.

Comment: Hmmm... I looked at the 'possible duplicate', but think that this is another variation of the same problem, but needing a different solution.  And yes, by "scraping" I mean am literally pulling Javascript code into the string.  I can't easily modify the javascript, but I suppose if I have to, I will.

Comment: I do think you will have to modify the code and export JSON instead of reading it. As it stands you're basically trying to directly translate a line of Javascript code into Python code, and that is just going to be a problem, they're not designed to interoperable. Better to use a defined intermediate format(i.e JSON) and parse that in your Python. But maybe someone knows something I don't and will answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that only first **key** is without quotes, then what if you just simply add quotes in the strings manually?
like this:

```
modified_strings_list=[]    
for string in string_list:
    string = string.replace('{','{"', 1)
    string = string.replace(':','":', 1)
    modified_strings_list.append(string)
```

And then apply `eval()`

any whitespaces can then easily be `strip()` -ed by looping `dict.keys()`

Comment: While my example may have only had one entry, I could have 50+.  Replacing ":" with '";' would work on one side, the other side is not a fixed string replacement.

Comment: can you give an example of multientry?