# Parsing javascript data structure in python

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I'm trying to find a parser for python that can parse the data structure (to a python dictionary) that is written below (this data structure was taken from `var` variable in javascript).

```
{
    a: "a",
    b: 54,
    c: [
        {
            d: "d",
            e: false
        },
        {
            f: "f"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: You could probably use `json`, which is Javascript-Object-notation after all...

Comment: Hmm, actually, no you couldn't, because `a`, `b` etc would have to be strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`demjson.decode()`](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/demjson-2.2.3/docs/demjson.html#-decode)

```
import demjson

# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = demjson.decode(js_obj)
```

### [`jsonnet.evaluate_snippet()`](http://google.github.io/jsonnet/doc/bindings.html)

```
import json, _jsonnet

# from
js_obj = '{x:1, y:2, z:3}'

# to
py_obj = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet('snippet', js_obj))
```

### [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

# from
js_obj = "{'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}"

# to
py_obj = ast.literal_eval(js_obj)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm supposed to somehow link the answer I got this from, so I copied/pasted instead. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary

Comment: The ; in the end needed to be removed from my string and it will work with demjson, Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these tools can be installed anymore