# Convert a string into dictionary

Tags: python

I have a .js file with the following content:

```
AppSettings = {
               projectName:'myproject',
               url: 'https://www.google.com',
               appKey: 'k2y-myproject_124439_18111',
               newsKey: '',
               version: moment().format('YYMMDD_HHmmss'),
               mixpanelToken: '08e97bef3930f330037d9z6t56395060'
              };
```

Which I would like to convert it into a python dictionary that I can access as follows

```
>>> print(data['AppSettings']['url']
>>> 'https://www.google.com'
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary

Comment: Here this a good example on how to [parse-json](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/#parsing-json)

Comment: @PetarP thanks. However, its not a valid json string

Comment: @labjunsky wait can you access it all ready

Comment: js files are for *javascript*.. where does python come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
d = {'AppSettings':{}}
with open('tt.js', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.strip().replace(',','').split(':')
        d['AppSettings'][splitLine[0]] = "".join(splitLine[1:])

d['AppSettings']['url']=d['AppSettings']['url'].replace('htt‌​ps//','https://')
d['AppSettings'].pop("}", None) #remove last item "}" from dict

print(d['AppSettings']['url'])
print(d['AppSettings']['newsKey'])
print(d['AppSettings']['appKey'])
print(d['AppSettings']['version'])
print(d['AppSettings']['mixpanelToken'])
```

Sample output

```
'https://www.google.com'
''
'k2y-myproject_124439_18111'
moment().format('YYMMDD_HHmmss')
'08e97bef3930f330037d9z6t56395060'
```

Comment: There is an issue here, that it strips the ':' from the url.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.. 
`d['AppSettings']['url']=d['AppSettings']['url'].replace('https//','https://')`