# Reading JSON data from JS file

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am uploading one JS file using HTML input file tag. I am reading the data in Python. Since in my data var `acb_messages` is written, I am not able to parse it. And I want to use this variable name to get the data so I can remove it.

```
var acb_messages = {"messages": [{
    "timestamp": 1475565742761,
    "datetime": "2016-10-04 12:52:22 GMT+05:30",
    "number": "VM-449700",
    "id": 1276,
    "text": "Some text here",
    "mms": false,
    "sender": false
    }
]}
```

How can I parse it in Python and then how can I use it?

Comment: please show what you've tried and the required output

Answer (score 8):

Two approaches that I would try if I were at your place -

1. Convert my .js file to .json file and then using method suggested by @Sandeep Lade.
2. Reading .js file as string, cropping out the value part and then using `json.loads(<cropped part>)` as suggested by @rahul mr.

Here is how to achieve 2nd solution -

```
import json

with open('your_js_file.js') as dataFile:
    data = dataFile.read()
    obj = data[data.find('{') : data.rfind('}')+1]
    jsonObj = json.loads(obj)
```

What's happening here is that you are finding first reading your .js file (that contains js object that needs to be converted into json) as string, find first occurence of `{` and last occurence of `}`, crop that part of string, load it as json.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

**Warning** - Code works only if your js file contains js object only.

Answer (score 2):

The options above are correct, but the JSON syntax in JS can be a little different than in Python:

example.js:

```
property.docs = {
    messages: {
    timestamp: 1475565742761,
    datetime: "2016-10-04 12:52:22 GMT+05:30",
    number: "VM-449700",
    id: 1276,
    text: "Some text here",
    mms: false,
    sender: false
}
};
```

Therefore we need one more tweak that I found at: [How to convert raw javascript object to python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary)

The complete code should be:

```
import json
import demjson

with open('example.js') as dataFile:
    data = dataFile.read()
    json_out = data[data.find('{'): data.rfind('}')+1]
    json_decode = demjson.decode(json_out)

print(json_decode)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
jsonfile=open("/path/to/json file")
data=json.load(jsonfile)
```

the above code will store will store your json data in a dictionary called `data`. You can then process the dictionary

Comment: This code wouldn't work with the given sample from the OP, because it is Javascript.