# Scrape page with "load more results" button

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the following page with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`/`Lxml`

`https://www.reuters.com/search/news?blob=soybean&sortBy=date&dateRange=all`

This is the kind of pages that have a `load more results` button.
I have found few pages explaining how to do so, but not within the frame of `requests`.

I understand that I should spend few more hours researching that problem before resorting to asking here, as to show proof that I ve tried.

I've tried to look into the inspect pane, into the network tab etc. but i'm still a bit too fresh with requests to understand how to interact with javascript.

I don't need a fully blown script/solution as an answer, just some pointers as to how to do this very typical task with `requests`, as to save me few precious hours of research.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry guys I had a wrong title before

Comment: `requests` won't run js, you'll need `selenium` for that

Comment: if you open network tab in developer tools in your browser and click load more results you'll see that button triggers ajax request to url `https://www.reuters.com/assets/searchArticleLoadMoreJson?blob=soybean&bigOrSmall=big&articleWithBlog=true&sortBy=date&dateRange=all&numResultsToShow=10&pn=4&callback=addMoreNewsResults` where pn=4 is page number. And responce is in json format. It also triggers some ping event, probably to make sure that ajax is running in browser (to bock automatic scrapers). So requests might work, but selenium or phantomjs is better choice

Comment: @mugiseyebrows, yeah i saw that too, but it won't be easy to use the data it returns. It seems like the data in `addMoreNewsResults` is not json (no double quotes in keys), but a js dict.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900181/2079189

Comment: @mugiseyebrows, yes, it's not impossible, but it would be easier to use `selenium`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick script should show how this can be done with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.reuters.com/search/news?blob=soybean&sortBy=date&dateRange=all"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

while driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.search-result-more-txt'):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-result-more-txt').click()
    page_num += 1
    print("getting page number "+str(page_num))
    time.sleep(1)

html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

I don't know how to do this with `requests`. There seems to be lots of articles about soybeans on Reuters. I've already done over 250 "page loads" as I finish writing this answer.

Once you scrape all, or some large amount of pages, you can then scrape the data by passing `html` into Beautiful Soup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":'search-result-indiv'})
articles = [a.find('a')['href'] for a in links if a != '']
```

Comment: I am getting an error that Selenium no longer works with PhantomJS "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '" and it won't run. Any suggestions?

Comment: @briancaffey how to limit the maximum page number, because the website detects it as a robot