# How to convert a complex string to list in python3?

Tags: python, string, list

```
s='[{affectedRows:0,data:[{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157193737,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598488770565),TSEND:new Date(1598488883573),DURATION:"000 00:01:53",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157187739,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598486907836),TSEND:new Date(1598486952947),DURATION:"000 00:00:45",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Night Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157140798,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598457456046),TSEND:new Date(1598457600090),DURATION:"000 00:02:24",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Night Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Night Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157082517,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598438706011),TSEND:new Date(1598438770312),DURATION:"000 00:01:04",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Night Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157022983,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598418938835),TSEND:new Date(1598419241188),DURATION:"000 00:05:02",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:157016784,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598417178457),TSEND:new Date(1598417524244),DURATION:"000 00:05:45",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:1,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"出口闭锁",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156770882,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"O",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX12.1",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.OutletBlocked.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598318321801),TSEND:new Date(1598318330198),DURATION:"000 00:00:08",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156770860,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598318305539),TSEND:new Date(1598318311616),DURATION:"000 00:00:06",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156770850,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598318299485),TSEND:new Date(1598318301485),DURATION:"000 00:00:02",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156770208,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598318125586),TSEND:new Date(1598318293513),DURATION:"000 00:02:47",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156755443,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598313672630),TSEND:new Date(1598313820398),DURATION:"000 00:02:27",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156586412,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598245145796),TSEND:new Date(1598245267127),DURATION:"000 00:02:01",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:1,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"出口闭锁",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156567889,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"O",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX12.1",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.OutletBlocked.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598239753597),TSEND:new Date(1598239769806),DURATION:"000 00:00:16",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156566901,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598239495914),TSEND:new Date(1598239755589),DURATION:"000 00:04:19",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156552663,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598233968242),TSEND:new Date(1598234023411),DURATION:"000 00:00:55",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Night Shift",TEXT:"位置无效占位",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156445504,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.2",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidOccupied.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598143424678),TSEND:new Date(1598173427224),DURATION:"000 08:20:02",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Night Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156350573,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598090562849),TSEND:new Date(1598090745901),DURATION:"000 00:03:03",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Night Shift"},{CONSOLEAREA:"PU011",ACTIVE:false,ISWARNING:0,PLCNAME:"面漆1线",PLC:"LF2911",ESTOPAREA:"B.5",INTERVALEND_ID:"Morning Shift",TEXT:"位置无效自由",DEVICENOTRELEVANT:false,FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION:"防爆区滚床",RECORDID:156276107,PANELAREA:"S02",FUNCTIONGROUP:"RB320",MESSAGETYPE:"T",ADDRESS:"DB2308.DBX8.3",VARIABLE_NAME:"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value",TSBEGIN:new Date(1598067289107),TSEND:new Date(1598067362857),DURATION:"000 00:01:13",MESSAGEGROUP:"FM",INTERVALBEGIN_ID:"Morning Shift"}],endRow:18,invalidateCache:false,isDSResponse:true,operationType:"fetch",queueStatus:0,startRow:0,status:0,totalRows:18}]'
```

I search on the internet, so I used ast package,but they didn't work

```
s_new=eval(s)
```

```
import ast

s_new = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

how to solve this?

Comment: I got it from web response, but can't be parsed. I don't know why.

Comment: it's definitely not valid JSON format. look into the api docs of the website? if it's public then you can share the link here as well

Comment: maybe it's not a valid json format, I got it from our internal website. I checked it, it is a list inside the "  "

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the simple python solution, if you don't want to write a parser and don't want to use javascript.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def date(val):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(val/1000)

s = '... your string ...'

temp = (s.replace('{','dict(').replace('}',')').replace(':','=')
     .replace('false','False').replace('true','True').replace('new Date','date'))

result = eval(temp)
```

Notice here, if you want to use this method, need to make sure there is not conflicting characters that will interfere with the `eval`.

This method is based on some observation of your original string:

the key in these are not quoted, so if you use `dict(KEY=Value)` in python, this doesn't require quote around key. Also, the dates in the string are actually `javascript` `Date` object, they are represented in the unix epoch time, so I need to use the custom `date` function to covert those timestamp to a valid python `datetime` object.

---

Old javascript method:

If you use javascript, this can be fairly easy:

```js
var s = "... your string here..."

var result;

eval('result = ' + s);

console.log(result)
```

Then if you like to use python, you can save the result to a real JSON string.

```js
var result_string = JSON.stringify(result)
```

Here is the output:

```
'[{"affectedRows":0,"data":[{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157193737,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-27T00:39:30.565Z","TSEND":"2020-08-27T00:41:23.573Z","DURATION":"000 00:01:53","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157187739,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-27T00:08:27.836Z","TSEND":"2020-08-27T00:09:12.947Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:45","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Night Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157140798,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-26T15:57:36.046Z","TSEND":"2020-08-26T16:00:00.090Z","DURATION":"000 00:02:24","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Night Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Night Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157082517,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-26T10:45:06.011Z","TSEND":"2020-08-26T10:46:10.312Z","DURATION":"000 00:01:04","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Night Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157022983,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-26T05:15:38.835Z","TSEND":"2020-08-26T05:20:41.188Z","DURATION":"000 00:05:02","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":157016784,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-26T04:46:18.457Z","TSEND":"2020-08-26T04:52:04.244Z","DURATION":"000 00:05:45","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":1,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"出口闭锁","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156770882,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"O","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX12.1","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.OutletBlocked.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-25T01:18:41.801Z","TSEND":"2020-08-25T01:18:50.198Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:08","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156770860,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-25T01:18:25.539Z","TSEND":"2020-08-25T01:18:31.616Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:06","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156770850,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-25T01:18:19.485Z","TSEND":"2020-08-25T01:18:21.485Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:02","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156770208,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-25T01:15:25.586Z","TSEND":"2020-08-25T01:18:13.513Z","DURATION":"000 00:02:47","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156755443,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-25T00:01:12.630Z","TSEND":"2020-08-25T00:03:40.398Z","DURATION":"000 00:02:27","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156586412,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-24T04:59:05.796Z","TSEND":"2020-08-24T05:01:07.127Z","DURATION":"000 00:02:01","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":1,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"出口闭锁","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156567889,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"O","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX12.1","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.OutletBlocked.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-24T03:29:13.597Z","TSEND":"2020-08-24T03:29:29.806Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:16","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156566901,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-24T03:24:55.914Z","TSEND":"2020-08-24T03:29:15.589Z","DURATION":"000 00:04:19","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156552663,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-24T01:52:48.242Z","TSEND":"2020-08-24T01:53:43.411Z","DURATION":"000 00:00:55","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Night Shift","TEXT":"位置无效占位","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156445504,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.2","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidOccupied.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-23T00:43:44.678Z","TSEND":"2020-08-23T09:03:47.224Z","DURATION":"000 08:20:02","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Night Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156350573,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-22T10:02:42.849Z","TSEND":"2020-08-22T10:05:45.901Z","DURATION":"000 00:03:03","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Night Shift"},{"CONSOLEAREA":"PU011","ACTIVE":false,"ISWARNING":0,"PLCNAME":"面漆1线","PLC":"LF2911","ESTOPAREA":"B.5","INTERVALEND_ID":"Morning Shift","TEXT":"位置无效自由","DEVICENOTRELEVANT":false,"FUNCTIONGROUPDESCRIPTION":"防爆区滚床","RECORDID":156276107,"PANELAREA":"S02","FUNCTIONGROUP":"RB320","MESSAGETYPE":"T","ADDRESS":"DB2308.DBX8.3","VARIABLE_NAME":"LF2911:Faults.S02.RB320.InvalidFree.Value","TSBEGIN":"2020-08-22T03:34:49.107Z","TSEND":"2020-08-22T03:36:02.857Z","DURATION":"000 00:01:13","MESSAGEGROUP":"FM","INTERVALBEGIN_ID":"Morning Shift"}],"endRow":18,"invalidateCache":false,"isDSResponse":true,"operationType":"fetch","queueStatus":0,"startRow":0,"status":0,"totalRows":18}]'
```

Then you can use python `json` to parse to list.

Comment: This is actually a good answer, because it gets the OP to a place where they can actually process that data in python.

Comment: @Zeitlin, it's a valid json string, so you can call `json.loads` on it in python to get the list.

Comment: OP? what does it mean?

Comment: @Zeitlin OP = Original Poster = you :-)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I tried ```json.loada```, It also show some errors

Comment: ```import json
# print(type(s))
s_n=json.loads(s)
print(s_n)```     ```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)```

Comment: @Zeitlin It works for me, using the steps described in the answer.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Could this be finished just in Python?

Comment: @Zeitlin I added a method that you can just use python. But the caveat is that some assumptions are made about the string, it's not robust enough, so use it with caution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-python-dictionary