# converting 2d json(?) array to pandas dataframe

Tags: javascript, python, pandas

I have used BeautifulSoup to collect a 2D data array from a website as a string. I believe that the table format is related to the json format, however, when I tried to apply pandas.read_json() on the string it gives a value error. I tried converting the "nul" to "0" and remove the "\n" from the string to no avail.

```
data_str = """[[{label:'column 1',type:'number'},{label:'column2',type:'number'},{label:'column 3',type:'number'}],
[205, null,  89748],
[206, null,  66813],
[235,   75,   null],
[236,  138,   null]]"""
```

I can convert the string to a pandas DataFrame by splitting the first row of the table containing the column names from the data entries, but this seems rather clumsy (see below).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ast

col_names, data_str = data_str.split('\n',1)
col_names = re.findall(r'label:\'(.*?)\'', col_names)
data_str = data_str.replace('\n','')
data_str = data_str.replace('null','0.')

data_arr = np.array(ast.literal_eval('[' + data_str))
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_arr, columns = col_names)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to convert the string to a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: This is an aside, and not directly related to the question as asked, but I would think that there was likely a better way to pull this information from whatever site into a dataframe.

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks for your comment, this is the first time I try something like this, so you are probably right. Could you be so kind to provide a hint how to proceed? [This](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/lines1.pl?composition=Cr%3A100&mytext%5B%5D=Cr&myperc%5B%5D=100&spectra=Cr0-2&low_w=200&limits_type=0&upp_w=600&show_av=2&unit=1&resolution=1000&temp=1&eden=1e17&maxcharge=2&min_rel_int=0.01&libs=1) is the cite I try to get the data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not a valid JSON but a javascript object as raw string.
You need install another module like demjson.
see [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900181/3214422) for more detais.