# Convert string to dict without using split in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

```
data = '{clientId: "300",id: "new",ctime: "6/3/2022",mtime: "6/3/2022"}'
```

I want data like that without using split:

```
data = {"clientId": "300","id": "new","ctime": "6/3/2022","mtime": "6/3/2022"}
```

Then access:

```
JO = json.loads(data)

clientId = JO['clientId']

id = JO['id']
```

OutPut:

```
clientId = 300

id = new
```

Comment: Is first line supposed to be string?

Comment: @matszwecja I think its supposed to be a json input

Comment: Yes its String @matszwecja

Comment: One more question, how are you obtaining that data? Because it's not a valid JSON string, and fixing it at the source might be easier than trying to re-parse it from this form.

Comment: yes i know its not valid json string i traying to convert valid json , and yes the data in source @matszwecja

Comment: its looking like javascript object to me

Comment: i think there should be a lib to do that ,right? parse js stuff to python?

Comment: If you have a valid JSON string, `json.loads()` should work. That's why I suggested fixing the strings at the source - if that source is JavaScript, `JSON.stringify` should work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert raw javascript object to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @matszwecja thanks, that was actually the one I was thinking of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to first add the quotes surrounding the keys to make that string into a valid JSON string, then convert:

```py
import json
import re

data = '{clientId: "300",id: "new",ctime: "6/3/2022",mtime: "6/3/2022"}'

valid = re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', data)
# '{"clientId": "300","id": "new","ctime": "6/3/2022","mtime": "6/3/2022"}'

json_object = json.loads(valid)
# {'clientId': '300', 'id': 'new', 'ctime': '6/3/2022', 'mtime': '6/3/2022'}
```

## Notes

- The regular expression `(\w+):` matches the keys
- In `r'"\1":'`, the `\1` part stands for the matched text in the above.