# How to parse relaxed JSON in pyspark with a "dynamic" schema

Tags: python, json, pyspark, fromjson, convertfrom-json

I have a dataset and one of the columns contains a string that looks like a "relaxed" JSON format (no double quotes around keys).

#1 I'm looking for a way to parse it out in pyspark - i tried from_json + schema but because it isn't the right JSON format so this didn't work (all nested columns resulted in NULL value)

#2 the keys in the json column can change depending on which questions users answered. In the example below it is question5 and question7, but in reality this key can change and so the structure of the values. How can i handle this "dynamic" format? Could someone share an example?

my dataset looks like this:

| customer_id | json_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { metadata: { version: 1. }, attributes: { question5: [ { provenance: { type: "confirmed", value: { origin: "ABC", timestamp: "2010-07-12T23:00:51Z" } }, value: { type: "struct", value: { response: { type: "list", value: [ { type: "stringValue", value: "import value 1" } ] }, category: { type: "stringValue", value: "job" } } } }, { provenance: { type: "confirmed", value: { origin: "ABC", timestamp: "2010-07-12T23:00:51Z" } }, value: { type: "struct", value: { response: { type: "list", value: [ { type: "stringValue", value: "address 1" }, { type: "stringValue", value: "address 2" } ] }, category: { type: "stringValue", value: "address" } } } } ], question7: [ { provenance: { type: "confirmed", value: { origin: "XYZ", timestamp: "2010-07-12T23:00:51Z" } }, value: { type: "stringValue", value: "yes" } } ] } } |

I was able to parse out the dataset in python using a series of json_normalize with for loops. However the tool i'm using requires pyspark instead hence the questions above. Much appreciate your time and help!

Comment: This data looks like js / node object format.  You could evaluate it directly in that worst case.  See the linked issue, you may be able to use json5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert raw javascript object to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027589/how-to-convert-raw-javascript-object-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Cireo thanks for checking! this is python though? i don't any any issue with python given that i was able to use json_normalize to parse out the components. However my ETL tool requires Pyspark only so i'm looking for a solution in Pyspark.

Comment: Ah, I misread that you were trying to do it without any use of python.  Depending on what control you have you may want to just force the input to be a real data format instead of this